# Login popup not redirected after successful login in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I trying a popup on clicking login window a pop up open with URL  it asking for  username and password as well as google signin
When the user tries to login using google sign in using pop up. After login the popup never redirects to the main page. But alert box with posting failed keeps on appearing

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".log-sign">Sign In/Register</button>

 <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
       
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <!-- Sign In Form -->
            <!-- Text input-->
              
               <div class="group">
<input required="" class="input" type="text"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label class="label" for="date">Email address</label></div>
              
              
          
            <div class="group">
<input required="" class="input" type="password"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label class="label" for="date">Password</label>
    </div>


   
               <div class="or-box">
                    <span class="or">OR</span>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <center><div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
              <div class="controls">
                <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();


      if(profile){
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'login_pro.php',
                data: {id:profile.getId(), name:profile.getName(), email:profile.getEmail()}
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }).fail(function() { 
                alert( "Posting failed." );
            });
      }


    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "alert box with posting failed keeps on appearing"?

Comment: After login it in index.php .fail(function() { 
                alert( "Posting failed." );
            }); Keeps appearing again and again

Comment: I think your backend implementation throws some kind of error. You might wanna check that

Answer (score 1):

You can try some of these:

1. check whether it reaches the success block or not
2. if it does try replacing

   `window.location.href = 'comments.php';`

   `with  window.location.href = '/comments.php';`
3. Or just simulate an Http redirect using:
   `window.location.replace("www.abc.com/comments.php");`

Comment: When page is redirected to some other page it works fine.. But while redirecting to the same page where popup is there it shows error .fail(function() { 
                alert( "Posting failed." );
            }); Keeps appearing

Comment: Do you want to close the modal when it goes in error block ? or the alert is being shown more than once ? If yes, please check  in your network call how many times you are calling the login API call.

Comment: Alert box keeps on apearing more than once..API is called only once

Comment: Your backend code needs a debugging then. There is something which Is causing it to go inside error block.